# deleting particular row in particular condition in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am newbie in spark. i want to delete a row using spark sql.due to incompatibility deletion in temptable so far i have read that ,operating delete  like sql queries i need to save the table in pyspark permanently that is hive table i guess.I have done that too
my code is

```
spark.sql("select b.ENTITYID as ENTITYID, cm.BLDGID as BldgID,cm.LEASID as LeaseID,coalesce(l.SUITID,(select EmptyDefault from EmptyDefault)) as SuiteID,(select CurrDate from CurrDate) as TxnDate,cm.INCCAT as IncomeCat,'??' as SourceCode,(Select CurrPeriod from CurrPeriod)as Period,coalesce(case when cm.DEPARTMENT ='@' then 'null' else cm.DEPARTMENT end, null) as Dept,'Lease' as ActualProjected ,fnGetChargeInd(cm.EFFDATE,cm.FRQUENCY,cm.BEGMONTH,(select CurrPeriod from CurrPeriod))*coalesce (cm.AMOUNT,0) as  ChargeAmt,0 as OpenAmt,cm.CURRCODE as CurrencyCode,case when ('PERIOD.DATACLSD') is null then 'Open' else 'Closed' end as GLClosedStatus,'Unposted'as GLPostedStatus ,'Unpaid' as PaidStatus,cm.FRQUENCY as Frequency,0 as RetroPD from CMRECC cm join BLDG b on cm.BLDGID =b.BLDGID join LEAS l on cm.BLDGID =l.BLDGID and cm.LEASID =l.LEASID and (l.VACATE is null or l.VACATE >= ('select CurrDate from CurrDate')) and (l.EXPIR >= ('select CurrDate from CurrDate') or l.EXPIR < ('select RunDate from RunDate')) left outer join PERIOD on b.ENTITYID =  PERIOD.ENTITYID and ('select CurrPeriod from CurrPeriod')=PERIOD.PERIOD where ('select CurrDate from CurrDate')>=cm.EFFDATE  and (select CurrDate from CurrDate) <= coalesce(cm.EFFDATE,cast(date_add(( select min(cm2.EFFDATE) from CMRECC cm2 where cm2.BLDGID = cm.BLDGID and cm2.LEASID = cm.LEASID and cm2.INCCAT = cm.INCCAT and 'cm2.EFFDATE' > 'cm.EFFDATE'),-1) as timestamp)  ,case when l.EXPIR <(select RunDate from RunDate)then (Select RunDate from RunDate) else l.EXPIR end)").write.saveAsTable('Fact_Temp1')
```

and after that i have got a permanent table in my pyspark

next i have queried delete operation

```
spark.sql("DELETE from Fact_Temp1 where ActualProjected='Lease' and  ChargAmt=0").show()
```

I have got this error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nOperation not allowed: DELETE from(line 1, pos 0)\n\n== SQL ==\nDELETE from Fact_Temp1 where ActualProjected='Lease'and ChargeAmt=0\n^^^\n"
```

I am a bit confused.is there any different way to write this. I have no idea why i am getting this error.Kindly guide me I am using spark 2.0
kalyan

Comment: Please add to your post: punctuation, example data and expected output. But either way, `DELETE` is not supported in Spark SQL as far as I know.

Comment: Firstly sorry for my weak english .ActualProjected  and ChargAmt are my column to play with . I want to delete  the table column values where Actualprojected is LEAS and chargeAmt is 0. so I want to  delete '0'value chargamt corresponding Actualprojected lease value. the resultant table will be non zero value whatever the Actualprojected value is. but is not Hive table support it ?. so far i have read from datastax that i can write Delete in hive context  that means in permanent table . i have got confusion here.what will be the exact approach to perform this

Comment: Why can't you just filter your data?

Comment: umm that's interesting . A worthy try thank you